# XCode: How can I verify an IPA is valid before uploading?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have a problem with creating IPA files and TestFlight is showing me this reason.

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402843-mismatched-keychain-access-groups

I get a mismatch with keychain access groups but it takes a while to upload the IPA file to TestFlight before it can tell me the file is not valid. I'd like to test the file before I even upload it. I would also like to know how to get information abou the IPA file so that I can diagnose and fix the problem. I have  no idea how it is failing since I am using the same Code Signing Identity in the Debug/Release builds as well as signing the IPA from the Archive. I have no idea what is wrong or how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Distribution Provisioning profile bundle identifier matches your App's bundle identifier (eg your bundle id is **com.mycompany.appname** and your App's bundle id has at least **com.mycompany.*** then you shouldn't run into this error.

Another way to check validity feedback in Xcode 4.3 is to archive the app, and hit the Validate button in the Archives section of your Organizer. (Note that it won't allow you to  to validate and gives a 'No application records found' error until you've created an App ID in your iTunes Connect account, and followed the steps until you've set it to "Waiting for Upload ". Don't worry if you're not ready to upload to the store yet, you can still validate without uploading anything.)

Answer (score 4):

[image: altool]

Go to terminal and use it like below

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool -v -f APP.ipa -u itunesconnect@user.com -p password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the altool that comes with Xcode

1. cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/
2. ./altool --validate-app -f <'ipaFile'>

Comment: This is not valid syntax...Either this `altool --validate-app -f file -t platform -u username [-p password] `  or that 
       `altool --upload-app -f file -t platform -u username -p password`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command to extract entitlements info from the signed application:

```
codesign -d --entitlements
```

Then try to compare it with the Entitlements part of provision profile. If they dont match there must be some problem with your signing process.