# I could't upload my ipa in Application Loader and i get the below error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa, codesign, application-loader

I could't upload my ipa in Application Loader and i get the below error.

> Could not find a CFBundlePackageType" within the Info.plist; or the
>   package is missing an Info.plist

when i install the ipa using iTunes i am not getting this error.

Confused on how to proceed about this?

Comment: Are you doing any repackaging of *ipa* using any script ?

Comment: Are you sure it installs through iTunes ? Can you check if the following key value is there in *Info.plist* `<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
 <string>APPL</string>` ?

Comment: Are you sure Info.plist is part of your project ?

Comment: Yes, Info.plist is in the project.

Comment: Is the key & value present in info.plist ?

Comment: Yes, Info.plist has the key value

Comment: I am using a script to repackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could be due to way you are packaging is wrong.

for instance

if I zip the payload like this then it causes above issue

and this is one of the wrong way to do

```
zip -r -s 64 Payload.zip Payload/
mv Payload.zip appName.ipa
```

The right way would be to use like below or use ***xcrun***

```
zip -r Payload.zip Payload/
mv Payload.zip appName.ipa
```

iTunes have so many validation so it finds out the problem.

To validate any *ipa* use ***altool***

Go to terminal and use the below script

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool -v -f APP.ipa -u itunesconnect@user.com -p password
```

Look inside your script it'll solve the problem

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028569/730807)